# How to copy file only if file sizes between src/dst differ?

Tags: bash, centos, cp

I wish to perform a file copy like:

```
cp --verbose /srcfile /dstfile
```

But I only wish to perform the copy if `dstfile` does not exist or if the `dstfile` filesize differ from the filesize of `srcfile`.

How can this be done using e.g. `cp` or other common file copying tool in bash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really not the most elegant way:

```
if [ -e /dstfile ] ; then
 destsize=$(stat -c %s /dstfile)
 srcsize=$(stat -c %s /srcfile)
 if [ "$srcsize" -ne "$destsize" ] ; then
   cp --verbose /srcfile /dstfile
 fi
fi
```

You could also try to get used to [rsync](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync)

Comment: Hm, ideally I'd need a one-liner, and like you say that seems complex. About rsync; do you think it can copy a single file or does it always take a directory as input?

Comment: Well, a one-liner wouldn't necessarily "seem" less complex, just wanted to point you in the right direction. I don't know what you want to achieve *exactly*. So try `rsync` with the switch `--size-only` or `--checksum`